# How to detect a frozen video stream in WebRTC

Tags: javascript, react-native, webrtc

Unfortunately, from time to time when making a one-on-one video call using `react-native-webrtc` one of the two video streams freezes or becomes black. Is there a way to detect when that happens programmatically? Thx in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like each video track has a listener that fires as soon as the stream freezes.

In react native it's the `onmute` listener:

```
stream.getVideoTracks().forEach(videoTrack => {
    videoTrack.onmute = () => {
        console.log("Frozen video stream detected!");
    };
});
```

Note that in React Native detecting frozen streams with this method only seems to work for remote tracks!

To detect if a stream is currently frozen I use ​the `muted` property on the video track:

`console.log(videoTrack.muted);    // true when frozen`

Another way I've found but haven't explored further is the `getStats()` method on the RTCPeerConnection. It returns a promise with a huge amount of data that can be used to detect frozen video streams and a lot more I suppose.

Comment: where did I execute this event on webrtc?